# wpdb get_var is not returning any result (verified mysql query returns only one value)

Tags: plugins, wp-query, database

I'm trying to modify a wordpress plugin to make it more adaptable for our needs.  I have a custom user_meta called practice and we separate our users based on practice, so we need to separate quiz results also based on practice.  My issue is that I cannot get my query to return the practice.  Can someone look at this and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
    function save_score( $json, $user_id = null, $practice = null )
    {
        global $wpdb, $data;
        $db_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'plugin_slickquiz_scores';


        $data    = json_decode( stripcslashes( $json ) );
        $set     = array();
        $now     = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
        $user_id = $user_id ? $user_id : get_current_user_id();
        $practiceKey = 'user_practice';
       // $practice = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value FROM $usrmeta WHERE user_id = $user_id AND meta_key = 'user_practice'" );
       // $usrlevel = $usrlevel ? $usrlevel : $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT meta_value FROM $usrmeta WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' AND meta_key = user_practice_level" );

        $userMeta = $wpdb->prefix . `usermeta`;
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT meta_value FROM %s WHERE user_id = %d AND meta_key = %d",$userMeta,$user_id,$practiceKey );
        $practice = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );

        $set['name']        = $data->name;
        $set['score']       = $data->score;
        $set['quiz_id']     = $data->quiz_id;
        //$set['createdBy']   = $user_id;
        //$set['createdDate'] = $now;
        $set['usr']         = $user_id;
        $set['usr_practice'] = $practice;




        $wpdb->insert( $db_name, $set );
    }

}
}
```

Everything inputs fine except $practice which does not put a value.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess meta_key is not a number, so you shouldn't use %d in yous SQL query.

```
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT meta_value FROM %s WHERE user_id = %d AND meta_key = %s",$userMeta,$user_id,$practiceKey );  // meta_key = %s not %d
```

PS. You don't have to escape table name in this way. You can use

```
$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} WHERE user_id = %d AND meta_key = %s", $user_id, $practiceKey );
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!  That was driving me crazy.  So %d is for number (digit?) and %s is for string I'll remember that.

Comment: In fact, you _can't_ escape the table name in that way. You will end up with quotes around the table name and end up with a MySQL error.